# column-count not works for table element in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

It seems Firefox cannot separate table element into multiple columns. Here is an example: http://dabblet.com/gist/5608442

It works in all modern browsers but not Firefox. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gecko doesn't support dynamic re-pagination of tables, because the mechanism it uses to implement correct handling of thead/tfoot when paginating doesn't support it.  That means no table breaks across columns, since those really do have to be dynamic (unlike printing)....